# How to execute Dotnet nuke project with jmeter

Tags: asp.net, jmeter, automated-tests

I have a Asp.net project and i want to test it with Jmeter. My issue is that, the Response data of pages are 'Object moved to here'. I have added Regular Expression Extractor and have extracted the __Viewstate and __Eventvalidation and passed it to the pages. But still i have the 'Object moved to here' message as Response data.

Answer (score 0):

I worth checking out [ASP.NET Login Testing with JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/aspnet-login-testing-jmeter), it provides login example for dotnetnuke followed by several troubleshooting tips.